# get #pathdaily image from twitterAPI

Tags: javascript, twitter-oauth

There is any way how to get #pathdaily image from twitterAPI

Here my code to get image from twitter search:

```
wall.fitWidth();
                            var html = "";
                            var y = 0;
                            console.log("data.length"+data.length);
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                img = '';
                                url = 'http://twitter.com/' + data[i].user.screen_name + '/status/' + data[i].id_str;

                                try {
                                    if (data[i].entities['media']) {
                                        /* img = '<a href="' + url + '" target="_blank"><img src="' + data[i].entities['media'][0].media_url + '" /></a>'; */
                                        img = data[i].entities['media'][0].media_url;
                                    }
                                    if (data[i].extended_entities['media']) {
                                        /* img = '<a href="' + url + '" target="_blank"><img src="' + data[i].extended_entities['media'][0].media_url + '" /></a>'; */
                                        img = data[i].extended_entities['media'][0].media_url;
```

The problem is if i search twitter by hashtag #pathdaily, i cannot get any images. i only get Path moment url. Then how i can get images from the path moment???

Here the example respond from twitter resful API:

```
{
        "created_at": "Tue Dec 06 23:34:22 +0000 2016",
        "id": 806280654988066816,
        "id_str": "806280654988066816",
        "text": "#pathdaily [pic] \u2014 https:\/\/t.co\/r6zHMSOMPf",
        "truncated": false,
        "entities": {
            "hashtags": [{
                "text": "pathdaily",
                "indices": [0, 10]
            }],
            "symbols": [],
            "user_mentions": [],
            "urls": [{
                "url": "https:\/\/t.co\/r6zHMSOMPf",
                "expanded_url": "https:\/\/path.com\/p\/3X8SYI",
                "display_url": "path.com\/p\/3X8SYI",
                "indices": [19, 42]
            }]
        },
```

Comment: so, to make sure I'm understanding your question properly, you want to retrieve a link to a tweeted image?

Comment: tweeted image, but it have no entities url. because the images was in twitter card form